# File not uploading in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file in Django to models:

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    kyc_verified = models.BooleanField('kyc status',default=False)
    aadhar = models.FileField(upload_to='aadhar_images')
    pan = models.FileField(upload_to='pan_images')
    gts = models.FileField(upload_to='gts')
    registration = models.FileField(upload_to='registration')
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    manage_mobile = models.IntegerField()
```

And in media, I have created the folders `aadhar_images`, `pan_images`,`gts`,`registration`. But when I am uploading a file using the form in html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'dealer:update' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<br><br>
AAdhar upload :
<input type="file" name="aadhar" id="aadhar" accept="*"><br><br>
Pan upload :
<input type="file" name="pan" id="pan" accept="*"><br><br>
Gts upload :
<input type="file" name="gts" id="gts" accept="*"><br><br>
Registration upload :
<input type="file" name="registration" id="regis" accept="*"><br><br>
</form>
```

and in views.py:

```
def update(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        user = User.objects.filter(username=request.user).values()[0]['id']
        try:
            aadhar = request.FILES['aadhar']
            print(aadhar)
            Dealer.objects.filter(user=user).update(aadhar=aadhar,kyc_verified=False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            pan = request.FILES['pan']
            Dealer.objects.filter(user=user).update(pan=pan,kyc_verified=False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            gts = request.FILES['gts']
            Dealer.objects.filter(user=user).update(pan=gts,kyc_verified=False)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            reg = request.FILES['registration']
            Dealer.objects.filter(user=user).update(registration=reg,kyc_verified=False)
        except:
            pass
```

After i submit the form, the files are not uploaded to their respective directories. Also the url in the database is showing as `media/filename`, but the files are not uploaded even in the media directory also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.update()` method doesn't save any files into the storage. You need to use the models `save` method. Also don't use try-except in such a way a simple `if` would suffice or you can simply use `.get()`. Since your model Dealer has a One to One relationship with user you can simply get the dealer as `user.dealer`. Try this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = request.user # Why so much work to get what you already have even if you want id request.user.id would be enough...
    dealer = user.dealer
    if dealer:
        aadhar = request.FILES.get('aadhar')
        pan = request.FILES.get('pan')
        gts = request.FILES.get('gts')
        reg = request.FILES.get('registration')
        dealer.aadhar = aadhar
        dealer.pan = pan
        dealer.gts = gts
        dealer.reg = reg
        dealer.kyc_verified = False
        dealer.save()
```

As a note it would be much better and easier to use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. Regarding the try except code, I asked in the previous question how to modify the code here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66186206/simplify-form-submission-in-django